# Get postgres function returned data java jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a proc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.proc_name(_user_id integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(earned numeric, date_of_expiry timestamp with time zone)
```

I am calling this from my repository

```
 @Transactional
    @Query(value = "select * from public.proc_name(:userId\\:\\:int)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AbcInterFace> callAbc(long userId);
```

I am not getting returned `TABLE` data. How con I get this returned data.

Thank you

Comment: Post the entire function. We cannot tell what the function is doing with only the declaration. Also what exactly do you get if not a returned table. Is there an error, if so what is the complete message? Is it something else, again if so what?